# Animations not triggering in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, tsx

I have created an animated view object in my RN app, inside HomeScreen.jsx that displays a success message when a user creates or edits a profile. The message is supposed to fade away over a 6 second period. Ive tried a dozen different ways to code this and all of them should work but none of them do. The message will display properly but the fade animation will never trigger.

The most recent attempt involves forcing a screen re-render using useEffect. I've also tried implementations using useState and useFocusEffect/useCallback. The fadeAnim value is used as the opacity for the animated view:

```
const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  // Here, I'm adding a listener to the Animated value to track its changes.
  // This is to show that the fadeAnim value is indeed changing as it should.
  fadeAnim.addListener(value => {
    console.log('fadeAnim value:', value);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    triggerRefresh; // this is supposed to force a screen refresh
    const fadeOut = Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 6000,
      useNativeDriver: true, //using native driver for best performance
    });

    fadeOut.start();
  }, [fadeAnim, message, refreshKey]); // passing refreshKey to force refresh

  const triggerRefresh = () => {
    setRefreshKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1); // incrementing refreshKey
  };
```

When the app is reloaded in the simulator, the fadeAnim value decrements as it should from 1 to 0, causing the fade effect, but at this point there is no message to display. When HomeScreen.jsx is returned to with a message in tow, the fadeAnim value is still at 0, when it should be reset to 1. I have no idea how to implement this very simple sounding animation. Please Help!